# Maximum possible memory usage: 143.5G (232.47% of installed RAM)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Kindly help me to tune my mysql.I am using mysql 8 ubuntu ,64GB RAM 16core CPU
Following are the configurations i did and the load connected.

ShowGlobalVariables

https://pastebin.com/8fqTmJWi

show global status
https://pastebin.com/38NUKW8v

processlist

https://pastebin.com/L9L9SajZ

mysqltuner
https://pastebin.com/M5xs0tT0

tuning-primer.sh
https://pastebin.com/sj5KiZzV

htop
[image]

I need 10000 concurrent users to work.The above configurations was upto 1200.What all changed i need to make in db.How much ram I should increase for that.Kindly help me to configure .I am getting tuner error as Maximum possible memory usage.
Thank you

Comment: Consider using a connection pool instead of trying to accommodate 10000 concurrent sessions.

Comment: Thank you.How can we do this ?Is there any document regarding this?and How much ram required for this

Comment: 10K?  What do you mean by "concurrent"?  10K different users logging in sometime during the same day?  During the same _second_?  Let's talk about "queries per second".

Comment: Thank you Mr.Rick.It is for and online exam portal.Users are login in a period of time and attending multiple choice quizzes. I did updation to mariadb 10.4  i will give you the results in pastebin.

Comment: After upgrading i kept the following results Global Variable-https://pastebin.com/w1fVAMk8
Global Status-https://pastebin.com/emdxi6YV
My.cnf https://pastebin.com/Pj80qGhc
Process list https://pastebin.com/bihTVdjT
Ulimt= https://pastebin.com/xjTKjjcg

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of `SHOW VARIABLES` was chopped off; try again.  (I need some of that info to finish my critique.)

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` shows about 250 queries per second, which is reasonable.  That may be coming from 10K users; I can't tell, and it does not matter.  Or maybe 302 users?

10K queries per second may be practical; it depends.

> 143.5G (232.47% of installed RAM)

That computation is bogus and should be ignored.  There is no formula that accurately shows the memory that MySQL *might* use.

The `STATUS` shows only 302 connections in more than a day.  This does not agree with your 1200.

What kinds of queries will be run?  This has a *big* impact on how much you can throw at the system.

Current table_open_cache = 48000 tables -- unreasonably high

Current key_buffer_size = 512 M -- Since MyISAM is turned off, set this to 0.

**Students taking test**

- 10000 students taking a test at the *same time*.
- 100 questions
- Somewhat evenly spread across 1 hour.

That would be 1M IODKU/hour = 300/second.  (Let's say 500 at peak.)

- The disk should be SSD.  HDD cannot keep up without taking other actions (RAID, batching, etc).
- RAM should be big enough to not need any extra reads.  Probably even a small server would have plenty of RAM for this task.
- Various settings should be unreasonably high to allow all 10K users to login and stay logged in.  See below.
- Connection pooling is not useful.
- To make room for lots of connections, other things should be kept low.  For example, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` -- Set to 1.  This increases I/O, but if the server crashes, you don't want hundreds of students grumbling that the server lost the last answer they provided.

**Tentative settings:**

```
max_connections = 11000
threads_cache_size = 11000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
wait_timeout = 4000  -- ??  Not sure which setting needs this
```

There may be more recommendations.  Your use case is abnormal; it will take some more time to think through the issues.  Do you have more comments on task?  Check my numbers and assumptions; elaborate further.

10K connections is a lot; I don't know how much space each connection consumes.  (And it may vary with OS and version.)  If you have a way to simulate it, please try to do so.  (Check mem usage with 1 connection on a cold system, then 1001.)  We will have to rob some things (eg buffer_pool) to pay for the connections.  Also, `table_open_cache` (and a couple of related settings) may get involved.  Probably every student will have the same few tables open; but I don't know if that counts as 1 per table or 1 per student per table.

Or...  Do you send everything through an API.  That is, should I be looking at "1" or "10000" for some of these metrics?  It makes a big difference.  Please provide more details on the interface between a student and the table(s).

If the problem has been pushed back into the web server, how many 'children' is it configured for?  There is a tradeoff between that and MySQL's "connection".  Again, I need more config info *outside* of MySQL to help with your Question.

**Chicken and egg**

I assume the `VARIABLES` and `STATUS` values were not taken during a "test".  So the status values do not reflect the actual use case.  Still, I intend to review them.

Comment: Global Variable-https://pastebin.com/w1fVAMk8
Global Status-https://pastebin.com/emdxi6YV
My.cnf https://pastebin.com/Pj80qGhc
Process list https://pastebin.com/bihTVdjT
Ulimt= https://pastebin.com/xjTKjjcg

Comment: @Dennis - Please sanity check the pastings.  This time about 20 lines are truncated from the beginning of the VARIABLEs.  (I did not check to see whether lines were also missing from the middle.)

Comment: if i paste above lines it is going above 512KB pastebin not allowed to copy i will keep balace here https://pastebin.com/WDM5nFD4

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connect_errors=10  # from 100 why allow a hacker/cracker so many attempts?
thread_cache_size   remove for auto-sizing by MariaDB
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # frin 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function
read_rnd_buffer_size=64K  # from 1M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 961
```

You will find these changes will reduce CPU BUSY.

Observation, Select_scan averages 2 per second - indexes missing.

```
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain   # to auto-explain the slow queries
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF for awareness and proactive reduction

log_error  being intentionally disabled is high risk. You will never know what happened - even 20 seconds ago.
```

Comment: @dennis Have you had an opportunity to apply the suggestions of July 11, 2020? Please Add Comment with either good or bad news.